# Codeigniter Config file, load a get function from model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a custom config file setup for twitter, which has some vars in but the data is saved in the database, so therefore i need to call something like:

```
$this->wc_settings->get()->row_array('consumer_key')
```

Here's the config file

```
$config['tweets'] = array(
'_tokens' => array(
    'consumer_key' => $this->wc_settings->get()->row_array('consumer_key'),
    //'consumer_secret' => '',
    //'access_key' => '',
    //'access_secret' => '',
),
```

This doesn't work but I need it to in order for the config file to work, but need to get the data from the database like shown above.
Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem ?

Comment: I have had to add the details manually for now, but i think I going to write a new library or something for it to grab the data etc. But thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically set the config in your controller or model using:

```
$this->config->load('tweets');
$dynamic_config = $this->wc_settings->get()->row_array('consumer_key');
$this->config->set_item('_tokens['consumer_key']', $dynamic_config);
```

Comment: No, you have to write this in your controller or model.

Comment: No i need it be on the config file i need to get the data from the database to thr config file

Comment: Config file has default and static settings.You CANNOT set values in config file dynamically. You can only set/update config dynamically in controllers or models
Just use the above code snippet before making a Twitter api call

Comment: Then i can do $this->config->set_item in my controller which is already there, but basically i have built a cms and when the user adds in there API details for twitter it gets saved to the database, so i need these details dragging to the config file as that where everything is stored, rather then manually typing everything in each time something changes, they can do it via the CMS

Comment: Do you see what I mean now i posted the above same to time you posted.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object                     like it doesnt want to get the wc_settings model

Comment: If you are using this in controller, load the model using $this->load->model('wc_settings') and if you are using this in model itself then $dynamic_config = $this->get()->row_array('consumer_key');

Comment: But the libray file looks to the config file for the _tokens array, so that's why i need to get the details from the databse to the config file, or is there another way? Because if this can't work then it make it hard should twitter change or the clients access codes change, they would have to do it manually via the config file, rather than simple way via the CMS

Comment: then set it to some random fixed value in config file but be careful to update config dynamically before making any twitter api call

Comment: Right ok i'll try that, or worse come to worse i'll do it manually or set it all in another library or core file.